# Update table with chapters, paragraphs and paragraph content using MySql version 8.0.17

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

In the table `t_contents` stored an a database `MySql version 8.0.17` I have these rows

```
+-------------------------+-------+-------+-----+
| Contents                | sID_c | sID_p | sID |
+-------------------------+-------+-------+-----+
| Content 1               |     1 | NULL  |   1 |
| - Gaio Giulio Cesare    |     1 | NULL  |   2 |
| Veni, vidi, vici.       |     1 | NULL  |   3 |
| Carpe diem.             |     1 | NULL  |   4 |
| Ubi maior minor cessat. |     1 | NULL  |   5 |
| - Quinto Orazio Flacco  |     1 | NULL  |   6 |
| Condicio sine qua non.  |     1 | NULL  |   7 |
| Carthago delenda est.   |     1 | NULL  |   8 |
| Content 2               |     2 | NULL  |   9 |
| - Marco Porcio Catone   |     2 | NULL  |  10 |
| Inter sidera versor.    |     2 | NULL  |  11 |
| Content 3               |     3 | NULL  |  12 |
| - Marco Tullio Cicero   |     3 | NULL  |  13 |
| Vivere est cogitare     |     3 | NULL  |  14 |
+-------------------------+-------+-------+-----+
```

In the column `Contents` of the table `t_contents`:

1. The `Content X` it's a `Section`
2. The `- Gaio Giulio Cesare` it's a `Chapter`
3. The `Veni, vidi, vici`, `Carpe diem.` and `Ubi maior minor cessat.` are the paragraph of `Chapter`
4. etc...

I need update the value on column `sID_p` according to this scheme, it's possible?

```
+-------------------------+-------+-------+-----+
| Contents                | sID_c | sID_p | sID |
+-------------------------+-------+-------+-----+
| Content 1               |     1 | 1     |   1 |
| - Gaio Giulio Cesare    |     1 | 1     |   2 |
| Veni, vidi, vici.       |     1 | 1.1   |   3 |
| Carpe diem.             |     1 | 1.2   |   4 |
| Ubi maior minor cessat. |     1 | 1.3   |   5 |
| - Quinto Orazio Flacco  |     1 | 2     |   6 |
| Condicio sine qua non.  |     1 | 2.1   |   7 |
| Carthago delenda est.   |     1 | 2.2   |   8 |
| Content 2               |     2 | 2     |   9 |
| - Marco Porcio Catone   |     2 | 2     |  10 |
| Inter sidera versor.    |     2 | 2.1   |  11 |
| Content 3               |     3 | 3     |  12 |
| - Marco Tullio Cicero   |     3 | 3     |  13 |
| Vivere est cogitare     |     3 | 3.1   |  14 |
+-------------------------+-------+-------+-----+
11 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

The table `t_contents` is registered in a remote MySql database whose structure cannot be edited...

Any help would greatly appreciate... Thank you.

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for t_contents
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t_contents`;
CREATE TABLE `t_contents`  (
  `Contents` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sID_c` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `sID_p` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of t_contents
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('Content 1', 1, NULL, 1);
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('- Gaio Giulio Cesare', 1, NULL, 2);
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('Veni, vidi, vici.', 1, NULL, 3);
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('Carpe diem.', 1, NULL, 4);
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('Ubi maior minor cessat.', 1, NULL, 5);
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('- Quinto Orazio Flacco', 1, NULL, 6);
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('Condicio sine qua non.', 1, NULL, 7);
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('Carthago delenda est.', 1, NULL, 8);
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('Content 2', 2, NULL, 9);
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('- Marco Porcio Catone', 2, NULL, 10);
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('Inter sidera versor.', 2, NULL, 11);
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('Content 3', 3, NULL, 12);
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('- Marco Tullio Cicero', 3, NULL, 13);
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('Vivere est cogitare', 3, NULL, 14);
```

**update**

I want to dynamically generate in existent `Section` (*content field*) a `new Chapter` using

```
INSERT INTO `t_contents` ( Contents, sID_c, sID_p, sID )
VALUES
    (
        "- New chapter on existent Section",
        tsID_contents,
        NULL,
        NULL 
    );
```

and after add `new paragraph` on this `new chapter`

```
INSERT INTO `t_contents` ( Contents, sID_c, sID_p, sID )
VALUES
    (
        "New paragraph on the new chapter",
        tsID_contents,
        NULL,
        NULL 
    );
```

for this return I have added `- New chapter` on existent `Section` and `New paragraph` on the `- New chapter` on existent `Section`

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `world_test`.`t_contents` WHERE `sID_c`= 1;
+-----------------------------------+-------+-------+-----+
| Contents                          | sID_c | sID_p | sID |
+-----------------------------------+-------+-------+-----+
| Content 1                         |     1 | NULL  |   1 |
| - Gaio Giulio Cesare              |     1 | NULL  |   2 |
| Veni, vidi, vici.                 |     1 | NULL  |   3 |
| Carpe diem.                       |     1 | NULL  |   4 |
| Ubi maior minor cessat.           |     1 | NULL  |   5 |
| - Quinto Orazio Flacco            |     1 | NULL  |   6 |
| Condicio sine qua non.            |     1 | NULL  |   7 |
| Carthago delenda est.             |     1 | NULL  |   8 |
| - New chapter on existent Section |     1 | NULL  |  15 |
| New paragraph on the new chapter  |     1 | NULL  |  16 |
+-----------------------------------+-------+-------+-----+
10 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

the problem is when I try to add a new paragraph to an already existing section, because the new paragraph is not created in the selected chapter but in the last chapter inserted in the database table

for example I add `new paragraph` on the existent chapter  `- Gaio Giulio Cesare` for this return

```
+-----------------------------------+-------+-------+-----+
| Contents                          | sID_c | sID_p | sID |
+-----------------------------------+-------+-------+-----+
| Content 1                         |     1 | NULL  |   1 |
| - Gaio Giulio Cesare              |     1 | NULL  |   2 |
| Veni, vidi, vici.                 |     1 | NULL  |   3 |
| Carpe diem.                       |     1 | NULL  |   4 |
| Ubi maior minor cessat.           |     1 | NULL  |   5 |
| New paragraph on the chapter      |     1 | NULL  |  17 |
| - Quinto Orazio Flacco            |     1 | NULL  |   6 |
| Condicio sine qua non.            |     1 | NULL  |   7 |
| Carthago delenda est.             |     1 | NULL  |   8 |
| - New chapter on existent Section |     1 | NULL  |  15 |
| New paragraph on the new chapter  |     1 | NULL  |  16 |
+-----------------------------------+-------+-------+-----+
```

Instead I have in return

```
+-----------------------------------+-------+-------+-----+
| Contents                          | sID_c | sID_p | sID |
+-----------------------------------+-------+-------+-----+
| Content 1                         |     1 | NULL  |   1 |
| - Gaio Giulio Cesare              |     1 | NULL  |   2 |
| Veni, vidi, vici.                 |     1 | NULL  |   3 |
| Carpe diem.                       |     1 | NULL  |   4 |
| Ubi maior minor cessat.           |     1 | NULL  |   5 |
| - Quinto Orazio Flacco            |     1 | NULL  |   6 |
| Condicio sine qua non.            |     1 | NULL  |   7 |
| Carthago delenda est.             |     1 | NULL  |   8 |
| - New chapter on existent Section |     1 | NULL  |  15 |
| New paragraph on the new chapter  |     1 | NULL  |  16 |
| New paragraph on the chapter      |     1 | NULL  |  17 |
+-----------------------------------+-------+-------+-----+
```

The `New paragraph on the chapter` it's not stored in the selected chapter (*`- Gaius Julius Caesar`*) but in the chapter `- New chapter on existent Section`

How to do resolve this?

Comment: This is a quite awful way of holding data on a database.. Please take an hour or 2 and read a Beginners guide to Relational Databases

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm not the database designer in this case... I'm sorry... I have this and I have to work on this...

Comment: Why does a new chapter number not start when the new section "Content 2" starts? Do you have a mistake in your sample data?

Comment: @BillKarwin I'm sorry... I don't understand your question... the "Content 1" start with 1, the "Content 2" start with 2 and the "Content 3" start with 3

Comment: In the column `sID_p` what's the difference between "2" for "- Quinto Orazio Flacco" and "2" for "- Marco Porcio Catone"?

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for reply... the difference is the value of field `sID_c` the number of section... for  "- Quinto Orazio Flacco" the number of section is 1 for  "- Marco Porcio Catone" the number of section is 2...

Comment: I see that it is in a new section, but the chapter number does not change. I expect one of two chapter numbering policies: either a new section should start a new chapter, so "- Marco Porcio Catone" should be chapter 3; or else each section has its own series of chapter numbers starting at 1, so "- Marco Porcio Catone" should be chapter 1 of section 2. But you seem to use neither policy. I think you need to describe how chapters are numbered more clearly.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks for your help. I have to solve a problem and I have thought of this solution, but I am willing to follow the instructions of the database experts. Pls see **update** in the question...

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to use `sID` both as an auto-increment primary key and as a way to infer the hierarchy of sections/chapters/paragraphs.

The way to fix this is to add an attributes to each section and paragraph to note their order in the hierarchy:

| Contents | parent_sID | order | sID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Content 1 | NULL | 1 | 1 |
| - Gaio Giulio Cesare | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Veni, vidi, vici. | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| Carpe diem. | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| Ubi maior minor cessat. | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| New paragraph on the chapter | 2 | 4 | 17 |
| - Quinto Orazio Flacco | 1 | 2 | 6 |
| Condicio sine qua non. | 6 | 1 | 7 |
| Carthago delenda est. | 6 | 2 | 8 |
| - New chapter on existent Section | 1 | 3 | 15 |
| New paragraph on the new chapter | 15 | 1 | 16 |

I know you said in comments, "I'm not the database designer in this case... I'm sorry... I have this and I have to work on this."

I sympathize, but the current design won't work. If you must use the `sID` as the implicit order of content as well as a primary key, then you must renumber all the rows every time you insert content (at least all the rows following your new row).

Comment: Thanks for help. Really appreciated. But how to do fix this problem using Mysql?